# How to identify alert box or error message box after clicking on save button in the UiPath?

Tags: automation, uipath

Using UiPath technology I want to know how can I capture the saved or error message after clicking save.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ArunVinoth Can you guide what is the problem in this question.

Comment: Indeed you should write more text. Also include the text from the title in your description of your issue. Also more info about the issue and what you already tried would help even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **different** ways to solve your issue.

I would recommend you to use the **Element exists** activity.

So after your **Click** activity you add the **Element exists** activity:

- set the **Selector** property of the selector of the message box
- set the **Timeout** amount to about 3000, this means it waits up to 3 seconds
- under Output -> **Exists** you create a variable, let's call it "IsMessageBoxShown"
- now check this variable with the **If** activity
- so in the **If** activity set **IsMessageBoxShown** as Condition, in the **yes Block** you now can set all the things you need when a message box is open, and on the other way you can do the other things